# change src of video tag dynamicly in nuxt js

Tags: video, load, undefined, nuxt.js, refs

i'm using nuxt.js . i have a  tag and i want to change the src dynamically but i cannot call load() method to refresh the video and  start playing .

tag :

```
<video ref="videoPlayer">
```

"change video" function in nuxt methods :

```
 this.videoUrl = "new url";
 let videoPlayer = this.$refs['videoPlayer'];
 videoPlayer.load();
```

load() not working ! it has error . i cannot access load() method ! why ? what should i do ?

error :

```
cannot read property 'load' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define videoUrl in data:

```
data() {
 return {
  videoUrl: 'path/to/old/video'
 }
}
```

The template in html:

```
 <video
  ref="videoPlayer"
  muted
  controls
 >
  <source :src="videoUrl" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

In a methods or a Nuxt hook:

```
changeVideoUrl() {
 this.videoUrl = '/videos/home/intro-desktop.mp4'
 const videoPlayer = this.$refs.videoPlayer
 videoPlayer.load()
 videoPlayer.play()
},
```

Is important to define videoUrl in data to activate Vue reactivity system properly.

Comment: i have data()

i'm using it , but error come from load() method :

cannot read property 'load' of undefined !

Comment: I've implemented in my source code as above and works without errors.

Comment: :/ i remove the if from video tag and its working :| sh****t :| ::::: v-if="playing === true" only play if user click play video ! that condition was the problem :|

Comment: <video controls v-if="playing === true" ref="videoPlayer"> TO  <video controls ref="videoPlayer">